# Heroku Login: login is not a heroku command

Tags: heroku

I have tried

`$ npm install -g heroku`

`$ npm install -g heroku-cli`

and I have also tried downloading Heroku-CLI from the heroku site and when I attempt to run

`heroku login`

It comes back with

`Warning: login is not a heroku command. Did you mean join? [y/n]:`

I can't figure out what is going on. I have my environmental variables set up and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling heroku cli by `npm -g uninstall heroku cli` and then run `heroku login`

For more refer to this: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/855